# Туннель и тоннель

Tags: орфография

Поспорили с одним человеком: он уверяет, что правильно писать "тоннель" - через О. Посмотрели в интернете, там пишут, что грамотно и "тоннель", и "туннель". Действительно ли это так и, если да, то почему имеет место такое разночтение? Кстати, аналогичная ситуация со словами "ноль" и "нуль", а еще с устаревшей формой "нумер" (правда, я точно не знаю, считалась ли она нормой) и "номер".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Из словаря Резниченко (2009)

1) Тоннель и туннель. Возникновение: 19 век, от англ. tunnel

2) Номер и (устар)нумер/ Возникновение: 18 век, от лат. numerus - число.

3) Ноль и нуль, область применения может различаться. Возникновение: 18 век, от нем. Null из лат.nullus - ничто.

Таким образом, во всех случаях парные варианты соответствуют разному написанию и произношению (способы записи транслитерация и транскрипция).

Comment: нумер остался в слове нумерация, и это радует  в УМЕ. НИЧЕГО Вам нумер не напоминает,родного?

Answer (score 2):

Ноль и нуль

Вопрос
Как правильно: ноль или нуль?

Ноль и нуль в свободном, не фразеологизированном, употреблении - равноправны. Но в некоторых устойчивых выражениях эти слова не взаимозаменяемы.
Только нуль в выражениях: остричь под нуль; быть равным нулю; на улице на нуле; на нуле кто-что-нибудь, с нуля начинать (начать); сводить (сводиться); свести (свестись) к нулю; довести (доводить) до нуля;
Только ноль в выражениях: ноль-ноль, ноль внимания, ноль без палочки,
Нуль и ноль в выражениях: абсолютный нуль (чаще о человеке) и абсолютный ноль (термин).
Прилагательные нолевой и нулевой закреплены в устойчивых выражениях: нулевое окончание, нулевая стрижка.

Правильно
в свободном употреблении ноль и нуль. ( Грамота.ру)

Тоннель и туннель  - оба варианта равноправны

Comment: Серж, вместо всех этих правил удобно воспользоваться одним эмпирическим: форма ноль употребляется преимущественно в ударной позиции, а форма нуль является ее фонетической заменой в безударной позиции, что видно из простого примера: ноль целых пять десятых - отнять от нуля целых пяти десятых.

Comment: Вы правы, София. Только ведь есть и устойчивые выражения,в которых употребляется как нуль, так и ноль.

Comment: **София**, отличный совет, спасибо.